# Issues with installing openai module

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api

Trying to install openai but I keep getting this error

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\openai.exe' -> 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\openai.exe.deleteme'`

Heres the full terminal

```
PS D:\> pip install openai
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting openai
  Using cached openai-0.27.2-py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from openai) (4.65.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.20 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from openai) (2.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from openai) (3.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->openai) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->openai) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->openai) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.20->openai) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->openai) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->openai) (6.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->openai) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->openai) (1.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->openai) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp->openai) (22.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from tqdm->openai) (0.4.6)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: openai
  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\openai.exe' -> 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\openai.exe.deleteme'

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

I've tried to install it using both pip and pip3 but it still gives me that error.
If anyone knows how to fix this that would be great.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the heads up, went ahead and changed the full terminal from image to text.

Answer (score -1):

The issue appears to be a permissions one.
Try to run cmd.exe as Administrator, then retry pip command

Comment: No error when I try this but I still get those warnings and the script still says that the openai module is missing, maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: @ioow, according to [github answer](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9023#issuecomment-948283646) you may try to play with C:\Python3.X folder's persmissions

Comment: No, _don't_ do that. Only ever use Administrator or `sudo` with good reason. If this is the problem, it would be much better to create a virtual environment and install packages there instead. `pip`-installing packages to the system directory is a great way to break your installation.

Comment: @Chris yup, just learned that the hard way. VSC gets denied access to deleting the module and Administrator CMD says its not installed while the file is still there.

Edit: Managed to get it uninstalled after some thinkering with the python folder as coder1 said.